# What does the notation $\epsilon_{a..d} 1.1.1.1$ mean in the context of permutation matrices?

Tags: matrices, permutations, notation, permutation-matrices

I recently encountered the following paragraph in chapter 2 of *The little Book of Permutation Matrices* by Dennis Morris.

> Since they are square matrices, permutation matrices always have a determinant... we realize that the determinant of a permutation matrix will always be of the form
>
> $$det\left(\left[
> \begin{matrix}
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{matrix}
> \right] \right) = \epsilon_{a..d} 1.1.1.1 = \epsilon_{a..d} = ±1
> $$

I'm confused what the notation $\epsilon_{a..d} 1.1.1.1$ means in this context, though. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: That's wrong. The determinant of that matrix is $0$. Surely there is a typo.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, sorry, I wrote it down wrong. I updated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It's from *The Little Book of Permutation Matrices* by Dennis Morris. I updated the question. The subject is permutation matrices.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I edited to include that information. The title now specifies the topic, and the question body identifies the name, author, and chapter of the book.

Comment: The sign of a permutation that makes the matrix diagonal, then multiply by those diagonal entries $1.1.1.1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in this case $\epsilon$ is viewed as the sign function. It is a homomorphism from $S_n \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$. You can also view it as equal to $(-1)^n$ where $n$ is the number of transpositions in your permutation.

For instance your permutation matrix is the same as $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ which is comprised of two transpositions $(1\;2)$ and $(2\;4)$ so $\epsilon(\sigma) = (-1)^2 = 1$